# WPF binding not notifying of changes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, sorting, entityset

I have a WPF sorting/binding issue. (Disclaimer: I am very new to WPF and databinding so apologise if I am asking a really dumb question :-))

Firstly, I have a linqToSql entity class `Contact` with an `EntitySet<Booking>` property Bookings on it.

If I directly bind this Bookings property to a `ListView`, the application seems to correctly notify of changes to the selected item in the `ListView`, such that a textbox with `{Binding Path=Bookings/Comments}` updates correctly.

```
// This code works, but Bookings is unsorted  
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = contact.Bookings;
bookings.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

However, as I can't seem to be able to find a way to sort an EntitySet (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925567/how-do-you-sort-an-entitysett)), I am trying to bind instead to an Observable collection, e.g:

```
// This code doesn't notify of selected item changes in the ListView
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = new ObservableCollection<Booking>(contact.Bookings.OrderByDescending(b => b.TravelDate).ToList());
bookings.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

But this doesn't seem to notify the comments textbox correctly such that it updates.

If anyone has a solution for either sorting the data before or after its bound, or another solution that will work that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind to a [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) rather than the collection itself. That will allow you to specify whatever sorting criteria you require. Example:

```
var collectionView = new ListCollectionView(contact.Bookings);
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("TravelDate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = collectionView;
bookings.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Thanks, this sorts fine but it still fails to notify of selected item changes for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hainesy,

Does the `Booking` object implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify change in `Comments` property?

If not, you cannot expect `TextBox` which is bound to `Comments` property to be updated automatically when `Comments` change

Using `ObservableCollection` in this case will only get you the benefit of updating the view with changes when `Booking` objects are added or deleted from the collection

-Rajesh

Comment: The comments for a booking never change. What changes is the currently selected booking in the view. This all works fine when I bind directly to the unsorted EntitySet.