# What does P mean in C# Expression?

Tags: linq-to-sql, sorting, data-binding, binding, entityset

I am attempting to use the answer in post: [How do you sort an EntitySet<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925567/how-do-you-sort-an-entitysett) to expose an interface so that I can sort an EntitySet with a Binding list.  I have created the class below and I get the following compiler error: "The type or namespace 'P' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?).  Can someone tell me what the P means and which namespace I need to include to get the method below to compile?  I am very new to delegates and lamba expressions.

Also, can someone confirm that if I create a BindingList from my EntitySet that any modifications I make to the BindingList will be made to the EntitySet?

Basically, I have an EntitySet that I need to sort and make changes to.  Then, I will need to persist these changes using the original Entity that the BindingList came from.

```
public class EntitySetBindingWrapper<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    public EntitySetBindingWrapper(BindingList<T> root)
        : base(root)
    {
    }

            public void Sort<P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> expr, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        if (expr == null)
            base.RemoveSortCore();

        MemberExpression propExpr = expr as MemberExpression;
        if (propExpr == null) throw new ArgumentException("You must provide a property", "expr");

        PropertyDescriptorCollection descriptorCol = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = descriptorCol.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = descriptors.First(pd => pd.Name == propExpr.Member.Name);

        base.ApplySortCore(descriptor, direction);
    }
}
```

I finally got the code above to compile but, now I am getting an error when I try to call the constructor:

The following code where currentPredefinedJob.fkItems is the EntitySet results in error: Cannot convert from System.ComponentModel.IBindingList to System.ComponentModel.BindingList

```
var bindingWrapper = new EntitySetBindingWrapper<PredefinedJobsItem>(currentPredefinedJob.fkItems.GetNewBindingList());
```

And, the following code results in error: Error 8   Using the generic type 'MarineService.Tests.EntitySetBindingWrapper' requires '1' type arguments

```
var bindingWrapper = new EntitySetBindingWrapper(currentPredefinedJob.fkItems.GetNewBindingList());
```

Can someone tell me how I need to call this constructor and confirm how I would sort the resulting BindingList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the generic variable in either your class definition or method definition.

`P` will be the type returned by your function `expr`

```
public void Sort<P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> expr, ListSortDirection direction)
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the part about P being the type returned.  But, I cannot even get the class to compile with P in the method signature.  Is there a namespace that I am missing?  So far, I have included: System.Linq.Expressions, System.Linq.Data, and System.Linq.

Comment: Once I cleaned the project and recompiled, I was able to resolve that error but, now I am getting another once when I try to instantiate the list.  Would you mind taking a look at my code samples and corresponding errors in the modified post?

Comment: @Grasshopper - You haven't modified the method definition to include `P`?

Comment: I did modify the method but, now I cannot figure out the right syntax to call the constructor.

Comment: @Grasshopper - If you updated your code, you should update your question here with the correct method definition

Comment: I just updated the Sort method signature in posting.  The constructor is the same which is where I'm having issues.

Answer (score 0):

For calling the constructor, the following works fine:

`var w = new EntitySetBindingWrapper<String>(new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<string>());`

Is it possible the problem is coming in what you are doing inside of `currentPredefinedJob.fkItems.GetNewBindingList()`?